# Powermock ExceptionInInitializerError with Junit

Tags: java, spring, junit, powermock, powermockito

Unit Test setup

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(PGWService.class)
public class PGWServiceTest {
public static final String TEST_CLIENTTRX_ID = "12345";
public static final int TEST_SITE_ID = 0;
public static final long TEST_USER_ID = 12345L;
public static final int TEST_CURRENCY_ID = 1;
public static final String TEST_ACCOUNT_TYPE = "Test account type";
public static final boolean TEST_IS_DEDUPING = false;
public static final byte[] TEST_SSN_CRYPT = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
public static final byte[] TEST_TAX_ID_CRYPT = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
public static final String TEST_SSN_LAST_FOUR = "1234";
public static final String TEST_TAX_ID_LAST_FOUR = "1234";

@Mock
PGWBaseRequest request;

@Mock
PGWClient client;

PGWService pGWService = new PGWService();

PGWGetAccountTaxIDResponse expectedResponse = this
        .buildGPWGetAccountIdResponse(TEST_SSN_CRYPT, TEST_TAX_ID_CRYPT,
                TEST_SSN_LAST_FOUR, TEST_TAX_ID_LAST_FOUR);

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(PGWClient.class);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(PGWBaseRequest.class);
    PowerMockito.when(PGWClient.getInstance()).thenReturn(client);
    PowerMockito
            .whenNew(PGWBaseRequest.class)
            .withArguments(TEST_CLIENTTRX_ID, TEST_SITE_ID, TEST_USER_ID,
                    TEST_CURRENCY_ID, TEST_ACCOUNT_TYPE, TEST_IS_DEDUPING)
            .thenReturn(request);
    PowerMockito.when(client.getTaxIdInformation(request)).thenReturn(
            expectedResponse);
}

@Test
public void testGetTaxIdInformationHappyPath() throws PGWException {

    PGWGetAccountTaxIDResponse actualResponse = pGWService
            .getTaxIdInformation(TEST_CLIENTTRX_ID, TEST_SITE_ID,
                    TEST_USER_ID, TEST_CURRENCY_ID, TEST_ACCOUNT_TYPE,
                    TEST_IS_DEDUPING);
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedResponse.getSSNLastFour(),
            actualResponse.getSSNLastFour());
}

private PGWGetAccountTaxIDResponse buildGPWGetAccountIdResponse(
        byte[] ssnCrypt, byte[] taxIdCrypt, String ssnLastFour,
        String taxIdLastFour) {
    PGWGetAccountTaxIDResponse response = new PGWGetAccountTaxIDResponse();
    response.setSSNCrypt(ssnCrypt);
    response.setSSNLastFour(ssnLastFour);
    response.setTaxIDCrypt(taxIdCrypt);
    response.setTaxIDLastFour(taxIdLastFour);
    return response;

}

}
```

I tried to run the unit test, it failed in the test instantiate with the following error

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor7.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) at
>   org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:40)
>   at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:59) at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxy(ClassImposterizer.java:128)
>   at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:63)
>   at
>   org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(MockCreator.java:111)
>   at
>   org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:60)
>   at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:143)
>   at
>   org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.standardInject(AnnotationEnabler.java:84)
>   at
>   org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.beforeTestMethod(AnnotationEnabler.java:51)
>   at
>   org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.notifyBeforeTestMethod(PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.java:90)
>   at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:292)
>   at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
>   at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
>   at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
>   at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
>   at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
>   at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
>   at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
>   at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
>   at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:104)
>   at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
>   at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at  at
>   com.bdd.domain.biz.pgwclient.DynamicConfigListener.getAttributeValue(DynamicConfigListener.java:132)
>   at
>   com.bdd.domain.biz.pgwclient.PGWCommunicator.init(PGWCommunicator.java:95)
>   at
>   com.ebay.domain.biz.pgwclient.PGWCommunicator.(PGWCommunicator.java:83)
>   at
>   com.bdd.domain.biz.pgwclient.PGWCommunicator.getInstance(PGWCommunicator.java:62)
>   at com.bdd.domain.biz.pgwclient.PGWClient.(PGWClient.java:117)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to mock static methods with PowerMock it internally creates an instance of the class. So when you

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(PGWClient.class);
```

New instance of the class is created inside PowerMock. Your `PGWClient` class default constructor does some initialization calling static methods at this moment. This causes static mocking to fail.

You should check on Power Mock [Suppressing Unwanted Behavior](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Suppress-Unwanted-Behavior)

---

*EDIT*

From stack trace it can be seen that `PGWClient` is accessing instance of 
`PGWCommunicator` via `getInstance` method. There is some unwanted behaviour inside. You can

1. Suppress its behaviour using info from link above
2. Create a default (package) or protected `setInstance` method to replace object returned during tests
3. Ideally move from singleton instance fetters to DI. Such code is a way more testable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I added this in my code PowerMockito.suppress(PowerMockito.constructor(PGWClient.class));

Still not working

But if I deleted @Mock PGWClient client. It will work. But I really need that one

Comment: It looks like it failed in the @Mock PGWClient client. When it tried to instantiate this one, it got failed.

Comment: You stack trace shows that internally `PGWCommunicator` is created via `getInstance()`. I would suggest suppressing this object creation or static mocking its instance method. Sorry this is not superclass constructor as I thought.